# How can I get the file extension from the mimetype in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mime-types, file-extension

As the title says, I've got a file downloaded from a server and I know the mimetype of it, but how can I work out what file extension should be used for it when writing to storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hunting around on here, it was clear the answer involved Apple's Uniform Type Identifiers (UTI), but I couldn't find an example of exactly what I wanted to do. I'm sure this isn't perfect Swift code (I'm new to it as a language) because of how I'm handling the managed/unmanaged variables, but this does the conversion I need:

```
let unmanagedFileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, type as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue()
let fileExtension = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((unmanagedFileUTI)!, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension)?.takeRetainedValue()
```

Comment: Donot forgot to `import MobileCoreServices`